# How many stereoisomers are possible for the compound in picture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

[image: 1-(buta-1,3-dien-1-yl)-4,5-dimethyl-2-(penta-1,2,3-trien-1-yl)cyclohexane]

How many stereoisomers are possible for the compound in picture? I'm getting 8. Is that correct?

My approach was as follows: The left hand methyl groups may be both up or one up and one down. For each of these cases the groups on the right may be in $(E{,}Z'),(E'{,}Z),(E{,}E'),(Z{,}Z')$ configurations. So $4\cdot2=8$.

I think it is quite evident that carbon having 2 π bonds must be linear. I apologize for the non-linearity in the picture. I hope you will be able to understand the question otherwise.

Comment: Carbon with two double bonds is linear, not bent.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't have a better picture...

Comment: Good to know you understand that. (Also, drawing it the wrong way may earn you downvotes and close votes.) Now to the point. Your E,Z calculation is correct. As for the _"up or down"_ thing, the right-hand groups may **also** be either way, so it gets more complicated.

Comment: I get your point @IvanNeretin...its really getting complicated..

Comment: There are **4** chiral centers in the ring. The diene moiety (upper right) has 2 isomers and the lower right moiety also has 2 stereoisomers. So I counted 36 stereosiomers total.

Comment: @SteffX Can you explain your method in detail?

Comment: @SteffX 36 sounds kinda superfluous. Are you sure you didn't mean 32?

Comment: I'm getting something different.There are 6 stereogenic areas.So I just use $2^6$...is that wrong? @IvanNeretin

Comment: @SteffX  
I'm getting something different.There are 6 stereogenic areas.So I just use 26...is that wrong?

Comment: Half of those are enantiomers. Or rather, all those 64 are _pairs of_ enantiomers.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But according to Wikipedia "Enantiomers, also known as optical isomers, are two stereoisomers that are related to each other by a reflection: They are mirror images of each other that are non-superimposable. Human hands are a macroscopic analog of stereoisomerism. Every stereogenic center in one has the opposite configuration in the other." SO ENANTIOMERS ARE ALSO STEREOISOMERS.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoisomerism

Comment: Sorry, it is 64 stereoisomers, aka $2^6$ (I am tired on Friday)

Comment: So do you agree with $2^6$ @IvanNeretin i.e $2^5$ pairs of enantiomers?No mistakes in the formulation..right?

Comment: OK, then 64 it is.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hi.Can you answer this if possible?Its a similar question. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57761/how-many-stereoisomers-are-possible-for-the-compound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyclohexane ring contains 4 chiral centers, one for each carbon in the ring bearing a substituent. Also, the ring shows no plane of symmetry.

The diene moiety (upper right) contains 2 double bonds which could each be *E* or *Z*, **but** the terminal double bond has only one substituent, in other words it contains a $\ce{CH2}$ group, so there is no stereoisomer.

Now the fun part. The lower right moiety (which is quite unusual, btw) also has 2 stereoisomers. The $\ce{CH=C=C=C}$ is linear but its bonds cannot rotate freely. In fact, we could consider it as a simple double bond and the terminal methyl group can be *E* or *Z* compared to the cyclohexane ring.

There are 6 stereogenic centers so there are $2^6=64$ stereoisomers.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Identify all possible sources of stereochemistry. You got pretty far.
2. Determine how many isomers can derive from each. I think you went wrong here.
3. Do you have symmetry? Reduce accordingly.
4. Multiply all the numbers together.

In your molecule:

1. Double bonds:

   - the internal double bond in the residue on the top right
   - the cumulene, which also shows isomerism (*E/Z* for uneven double bond counts, a*R*/a*S* for even ones).

   Asymmetric carbons:

   - the top methyl group
   - the bottom methyl group
   - the cumulene-containing side-chain
   - the other unsaturated side-chain.
2. Every one of these can be either *R/S* or *E/Z*.
3. The molecule does not have any elements of symmetry, so we cannot reduce.
4. All we have are factors of 2; two from the double bonds, another four from the asymmetric carbons. This leads us to:
   $$n(\text{isomers}) = 2^{(2 + 4)} = 2^6 = 64$$